# Merge Dictionaries with different TimeStamp

Tags: python

Data1:

```
    Time                Header  Header  Header  Header 
    2015-08-01 07:00    14.4    14.4    14.4    68 
    2015-08-01 07:01    14.4    14.4    14.4    68
    2015-08-01 07:01    14.4    14.4    14.4    68
```

Data2:

```
Time        Header  Header  Header  Header  Header
07:00       34      31      37      51      72
07:02       32      31      17      56      12
```

I'd like to merge those two files so I get the output:

```
    Time                Header  Header  Header  Header Header  Header  Header   Header  Header
    2015-08-01 07:00    14.4    14.4    14.4    68     34       31      37      51      72
```

if there's no reference file for the timestamp I need only the Data1 one Line in the field so:

```
           Time                Header  Header  Header  Header Header  Header  Header    Header  Header
    2015-08-01 07:00    14.4    14.4    14.4    68     34       31      37      51      72
    2015-08-01 07:01    14.4    14.4    14.4    68    
    2015-08-01 07:02    14.4    14.4    14.4    68     32       31      17      56      12
```

The Data2 File is a reference File, with entries every 15 Minute while the Data 1 File has one File every Minute. For plotting purposes I want to add the reference file into the Data File. So I guess what I'm looking for is how to check only the %H:%M Part of the Timestamp and do the merge.
I tried the following: There are more Data1 and Data2 files in the Folder so the first thing I did, was looking for a Data1 File and a Data2 file that match (Datewise) and  put them in a File ---> Then I made a Dictionary out of it

```
for data1files in Data1_List:
with open(files) as csv_files:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_files, dialect='excel-tab')
    header_1 = next(csr_reader)
    for rows in csr_reader:
        k=rows[0]
        v=rows[1:4]
        Data1Dict[k]=v
```

same for the Reference File Data2:

```
for data2files in Data2_List:
with open(data2files) as csv_files:
    csr_reader = csv.reader(csv_files, dialect='excel-tab')
    header_2 = next(csr_reader)
    for rows in csr_reader:
        k=rows[0]
        v=rows[1:5]
        Data2Dict[k]=v
```

so The Keys in both Dictionary is the the first row: In Data1 it is `2015-08-01 07:00` and in Data2 it is `07:00`. Is there a cool way to compare those two Keys in order to merge the Date from the reference file on the right timestamps

Comment: you have a syntax error in `header-1 = next...`. Use the underscore `_`

Comment: thx fixed it to underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
merge_d = {d1k: d1v+Data2Dict.get(d1k[-5:]) for d1k,d1v in Data1Dict.items()
           if d1k[-5:] in Data2Dict }
```

is a dictionary with the values merged.

For example with:

```
Data1Dict = {'2015-08-01 07:00': ['14.4', '14.4', '14.4', '68'],
             '2015-08-01 08:00': ['15.4', '15.4', '15.4', '69']}

Data2Dict = {'07:00': ['34', '31', '37'],
             '08:00': ['38', '38', '39']}
```

it produces

```
{'2015-08-01 07:00': ['14.4', '14.4', '14.4', '68', '34', '31', '37'],
 '2015-08-01 08:00': ['15.4', '15.4', '15.4', '69', '38', '38', '39']}
```

Note: it's a brutal hard-coded solution which assumes the time has a positional and fixed representation (i.e. always hh:mm and always in the same place).

**EDIT after further details were added**

In case there may be no corresponding time in Data2Dict (i.e. the Data1 sequence has a higher sampling frequency than Data2) things are even easier:

```
merge_d = {d1k: d1v+Data2Dict.get(d1k[-5:],[]) for d1k,d1v in Data1Dict.items() }
```

with an input of

```
Data1Dict = {'2015-08-01 07:00': ['14.4', '14.4', '14.4', '68'],
             '2015-08-01 07:01': ['12.2', '12.3', '12.4', '99'],
             '2015-08-01 07:02': ['15.4', '15.4', '15.4', '69']}

Data2Dict = {'07:00': ['34', '31', '37'],
             '07:02': ['38', '38', '39']}
```

it produces

```
{'2015-08-01 07:00': ['14.4', '14.4', '14.4', '68', '34', '31', '37'],
 '2015-08-01 07:01': ['12.2', '12.3', '12.4', '99'],
 '2015-08-01 07:02': ['15.4', '15.4', '15.4', '69', '38', '38', '39']}
```

Comment: thanks that works nearly perfect. I think I wrote something wrong in my question: The Reference File (Data2) only has Data every 15 Minutes while the Data1 File has Data every Minute. I need a `merge`where the Data from Data2 is added on those Timestamp spots of Data1, when there's no Data2 Data for a Timestamp of Data1 I still need the Data on line in the File

Comment: are you sure you input/output data reflect what you are asking? My solution satisfies your words, but not the data...

Comment: Hmmm... well i tried your edited version and it does exactly what I need the code to do. I just needed everything in one cvs file so I can plot the stuff easier. All I needed was to copy the Rows from Data2 and copy it at the end of the Data1 rows. Doing that manually would not work since there are too many files (Data1 and Data2

Comment: would you mind explaining the merge procedure? where would I change the date format if I#d wanted to merge dictionaries with same timestamp

Comment: the dictionary comprehension above is quite simple: for all items of Data1Dict (key and value) catenate the value of the element in Dict2Dict which has a key equal to the last 5 characters of the current key. If it is absent, catenate an empty list (i.e. keep the current value as it is). About the format, I am not sure I understand what you mean